# Is there any way to dynamically synchronize selections between different data frames in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, data-frame

Here's the scenario:
I have two different data frames in ArcGIS (10.3.1). In both, a dataset is added from an Excel spreadsheet.

In one data frame (call it "Map"), a layer is created from x,y coordinates. In the other data frame (call it "TAS"), it is symbolized from the values of two different elements (think - local coordinates).

There's also a column called "ID" which is a unique ID.

I would love to know if there's any way of making a selection set in one data frame and have it dynamically update with the same selection in the other data frame (preferably two-way communication). So the problem is not only is it separate data frames but separate coordinate systems.

Comment: If selection is based on attributes, consider data driven pages and definition query. One way

Comment: Unfortunately, users are going to want to use the select features tools, instead of via attributes.

Comment: It is a script, very basic though

Comment: Yes, I was leaning towards a custom tool. Could you please expand on your script comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SCRIPT:

```
try: arcpy
except: import arcpy
# GET DATAFRAMES AND LAYERS
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
parentFrame=arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd,"MAP")[0]
childFrame=arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd,"TAS")[0]
parentLayer, childLayer="PARENT","CHILD"
parentLayer=arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,parentLayer,parentFrame)[0]
childLayer=arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,childLayer,childFrame)[0]
# CHECK SELECTION IN SOURCE
descParent = arcpy.Describe(parentLayer)
if len(descParent.FIDset)==0:
    descChild = arcpy.Describe(childLayer)
    if len(descChild.FIDset)==0:
        arcpy.AddMessage("No selection found")
        exit()
    else:
        parentLayer, childLayer=childLayer,parentLayer
selectedIDs= [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray(parentLayer,"ID")]
if len(selectedIDs)==0:selectedIDs.append(-1)
# SELECT CHILD
quer='"ID" IN '+str(tuple(selectedIDs))
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(childLayer, "NEW_SELECTION", quer)
```

EXAMPLE:
[image]

IMPORTANT NOTES:

- script tested on shapefiles, query syntax is different for features in database
- I assumed that your ID field is integer, query syntax is different for strings
- selection in TAS processed only when NO selection found in MAP
- If you add script to menu item, it will execute immediately without "NO PARAMETERS" window display